# Docusign Not Generating Multiple Embedded Recipient Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, docusignapi

I am using the Docusign Rest API, through a [gem for Rails](https://github.com/Hunter-Dolan/docusign_rest). I have 2 recipients, and need both of them to sign the document.

It should work like this:

- Generate envelope with borrower(s) info passing to the envelope.
- Display embedded document for signing.
- Return to custom url/action
- If there is another signer, *it should*

  - reload the iframe
  - ask for second signers signature, with the same template that was just signed

Instead it breaks when I reloads the iframe for the 2nd signer. It generates the envelope, with my second signer with its unique ID, email etc. However when I then create the recipient view, it returns nil.

**How do I get signer 1 to sign, then load it for the second signer right after, with all the custom fields filled both times?**

```
def deliver(signing_borrower)

    client = DocusignRest::Client.new
    hashData = {
      status: 'sent',
      template_id: my_id
      signers: [
        {
          embedded: true,
          name: signing_borrower.name,
          email: signing_borrower_email,
          role_name: if (signing_borrower==borrower) then 'Borrower' else 'Co-borrower' end
        }
      ]
    }
    generate_liabilities
    hashData[:signers][0][:tabs] = if (signing_borrower==borrower) then custom_fields else co_borrower_custom_fields end


    #if there is a coborrower, add that data to the form as the second signer
    if co_borrower
      if signing_borrower==co_borrower then opposite_of_signing_borrower = borrower else opposite_of_signing_borrower = co_borrower end

      borrower2= {
        name: opposite_of_signing_borrower.name,
        email: signing_borrower_email(opposite_of_signing_borrower),
        role_name: if (opposite_of_signing_borrower==co_borrower) then 'Co-borrower' else 'Borrower' end
      }

      #add second borrower to hash to generate envelope with all form fields filled
      hashData[:signers] << borrower2
      hashData[:signers][1][:tabs] = {
          textTabs: text_tabs,
          checkboxTabs: checkbox_tabs
        }
    end


    response = client.create_envelope_from_template hashData
    self.envelope_id = response["envelopeId"]
    self.signing_url = DocusignRest::Client.new.get_recipient_view({
      envelope_id: self.envelope_id,
      name: signing_borrower.name,
      email: signing_borrower_email(signing_borrower),
      return_url: return_url
    })

    response
  end
```

The hashData

```
{:status=>"sent",
 :email=>
  {:subject=>"Application...",
   :body=>"please sign...."},
 :template_id=>"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
 :signers=>
  [{:embedded=>true,
    :name=>"DAVID L. TESTCASE",
    :email=>"email@test.com",
    :role_name=>"Borrower",
    :tabs=>
     {:textTabs=>
       [{:tablabel=>"phone",
         :name=>"phone",
         :value=>"717-717-7171"}]
     }
   },
   {:name=>"MARISOL TESTCASE",
    :email=>"email2@test.com",
    :role_name=>"Co-borrower",
    :tabs=>
      {:textTabs=>
         [{:tablabel=>"phone",
         :name=>"phone",
         :value=>"717-717-7171"}]
     }
  }]}
```

Comment: I'm not very good with Ruby but I know DocuSign.  It's hard for me to tell what your request body looks like.  Can you please update your question and add the JSON request body that this code creates?  That should shed some light on what's going on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you're trying to do by making 3 API calls:

1. **Create Envelope** request, specifying both recipients as 'embedded/captive' by setting **clientUserId** property for each recipient.
2. **POST Recipient View** request to get the URL to launch the ***first*** signer's signing session.
3. **POST Recipient View** request to get the URL to launch the ***second*** signer's signing session.

Here's example JSON for those three calls.

**1 - Create Envelope Request**

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes

{
  "emailSubject": "Please sign this",
  "emailBlurb": "Please sign...thanks!",
  "templateId": "064A7973-B7C1-41F3-A2AD-923CE8889333",
  "status": "sent",
  "templateRoles": [
   {
      "roleName": "Borrower",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "johnsemail@outlook.com",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "clientUserId": "123",
      "tabs":{
            "textTabs":[
               {
                  "tabLabel":"BorrowerPhone",
                  "value":"717-717-7171"
               },
            ],
         }
    },
    {
      "roleName": "Co-borrower",
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "email": "janesemail@outlook.com",
      "recipientId": "2",
      "clientUserId": "567",
      "tabs":{
            "textTabs":[
               {
                  "tabLabel":"Co-borrowerPhone",
                  "value":"717-717-7171"
               },
            ],
         }
    }
  ]
}
```

A successful response will contain the Id of the newly created Envelope.

**2 - POST Recipient View (for the First Recipient)**

Make this call when the first signer is ready to sign.  In the request URL, **{{envelopeId}}** is the Envelope Id value that was returned in the response of the **Create Envelope** request, and information in the request body corresponds to info you submitted for the *first* recipient in the **Create Envelope** request.

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/views/recipient

{
     "authenticationMethod": "Email",
     "clientUserId": "123",
     "userName": "John Doe",
     "email": "johnsemail@outlook.com",
     "returnUrl": "http://www.google.com"
}
```

The response will contain the URL that can be used to launch the DocuSign Envelope for the first recipient.

**3 - POST Recipient View (for the Second Recipient)**

Make this call when it's time for the second signer to sign.  In the request URL, **{{envelopeId}}** is the Envelope Id value that was returned in the response of the **Create Envelope** request, and information in the request corresponds to info you submitted for the *second* recipient in the **Create Envelope** request.

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/views/recipient

{
     "authenticationMethod": "Email",
     "clientUserId": "567",
     "userName": "Jane Doe",
     "email": "janesemail@outlook.com",
     "returnUrl": "http://www.google.com"
}
```

The response will contain the URL that can be used to launch the DocuSign Envelope for the second recipient.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the JSON request body that you're building.  I'm curious where you added the `embedded => true` property from, that's not in the API docs or examples.  As far as I know that is not a valid property, but I think the DocuSign API is forgiving in that it doesn't error out when non-recognized properties are sent, it ignores them instead.

In general, when you are creating Embedded (aka "Captive") recipients you need to configure at least 3 properties for these recipients:

```
1.  email
2.  name
3.  clientUserId
```

All of these are client configurable (i.e. you can set them to whatever you want), however whatever values you use when adding each recipient.. you need to reference the same exact values when requesting a signing URL for them.

For example, to add two embedded recipients you can send the following (partial) request body:

```
"signers": [
    {
        "name": "Sally Doe",
        "email": "test_1@email.com"
        "clientUserId": "1000"
    },
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "test_2@email.com"
        "clientUserId": "1001"
    }
]
```

If you do not specify the `routingOrder` for your recipients then it will default to routing order = 1.  And if you don't specify a recipientId, the system will generate a unique GUID for each and assign to them.

---

Once your envelope has been created and your recipients have been added to it, you can then request the signing URLs, but as mentioned you'll need to reference the same values for `name`, `email`, and `clientUserId`.

For more info you can check out the page on Embedding functionality at the DocuSign Developer Center:

http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features

Comment: Thanks for the info. (FYI, Embedded comes from here https://github.com/Hunter-Dolan/docusign_rest).

So if I load the page once with `signers: [signer1,signer2]`, and then reload it with `[signer2,signer1]`, and update the `request_signing` to match whichever signer is first, shouldn't that work?

Comment: Basically, you can accomplish everything in just two api calls.  The first call will be to create the envelope with 2 embedded recipients (add `clientUserId` property for each recipient), and give them routingOrders 1 and 2.  Once the first recipient signs, then you make the second api call, which will be to request the signing URL token for the next recipient.  That should be all you have to do.  This is exactly done in API Walkthrough #8 (Embedded SIgning), except that you need to add the second recipient in and request the 2nd signing url:  http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs